# Iterating through website links and clicking them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, watir

```
@editLinks = $ie.link(:text => "Edit", :class =>"edit" ).links
@editLinks.each do  |l| l.click 
end
```

I have the above code which iterates through a set of links which are called "Edit". When edit is clicked on the webpage, the text boxes become enabled and the user is able to type into them. There are different edit links for different textboxes. However, for some reason, the code is not iterating or giving me any errors. It just finishes the script without clicking any edit links. I've omitted the javascript onlcick stuff to show just the html. All the edit links on the webpage also have different ID's.

```
<a id="EditLinkButton" class="edit"><strong>Edit</strong></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [Get Elements By Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434697/get-elements-by-attributes) question, I'd suggest doing something like the following:

```
@editLinks = $ie.links
@editLinks.each do |link|
  if link.attribute_value("class") == "edit" and link.text == "Edit"
    link.click
  end
end
```

There's probably a better way of doing this, but it works.

Edit:

After reading your comment below, perhaps something along the lines of this would be better

```
@edit_ids = %w(your edit link ids seperated by whitespace)
@edit_ids.each do |edit_id|
  $ie.link(:id => edit_id).click
  # whatever else you're doing
end
```

So that way you're looking them up in the DOM as and when you need them, rather than storing them and then their references becoming obsolete as the page changes during the test.  Worth a shot.

Comment: I've still been unsuccessful, using the code that you've written doesn't do anything for me in IE8 but clicks only 1 edit link in firefox/chrome through watir webdriver. the cmd output says "element no longer attached to DOM". This true since once the link is clicked it disappears because it been programmed to disapear after its been clicked and reappear once save is clicked. But, the other edit links are still present and are not clicked.

Comment: After reading: http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/02/watir-webdriver-obselete-element-error/ this fella, it seems like the Watir-Webdriver way of locating DOM elements actually prevents you from looping through easily on pages that rely on javascript.

Comment: Have a look at the part I added to the original answer.  Might be what you need, but I didn't test it so beware my constant typos and mistakes :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, just what I needed! Awesome find, cant believe i overlooked watirmelon :D.